# Android app crashing while starting

Tags: android, android-studio

**This is the error(Have replaced app details with blanks)**. I was able to deploy the apk properly but when the app is starting, it crashes with the below error.

```
09-11 21:40:29.588 2819-2871/----- E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegIntentService]
Process:------, PID: 2819
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.Fileandroid.suppo
rt.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was
expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct
(declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in
/data/app/<app_name>-1/base.apk)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.shopping.gcm.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationInten
tService.java:65)
at
android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 09-11 21:40:30.444
2819-2870/-------- W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not
implemented 09-11 21:40:30.444 2819-2870/-------
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f205c1654c0,
error=EGL_SUCCESS 09-11 21:40:30.778 2819-2819/-------
I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much
work on its main thread. 09-11 21:40:30.840
2819-2870/------- E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked:
unknown buffer: 0x7f205c1436c0 09-11 21:40:30.978
2819-2870/--------- E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked:
unknown buffer: 0x7f205c142150 09-11 21:40:34.204
2819-2871/------- I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2819 SIG:
9
```

**These are the gradle file details:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "------"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.2.2"

    }
}
task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "default"
    reportLevel = "medium"
    excludeFilter = new File("${project.rootDir}/findbugs/findbugs-filter.xml")
    classes = files("${project.rootDir}/app/build/intermediates/classes")
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classpath = files()
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/findbugs/findbugs-output.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$project.buildDir/findbugs/findbugs-output.html"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.jar')
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.github.eluleci:flatui:3.0.0'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.vlonjatg.android:progress-activity:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    //    // Testing dependencies

    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'

    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'

    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.jar')
}
```

**Any ideas on how can I resolve this?**

Answer (score 3):

Try to use latest compiles

For eg: 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

Maybe the isssue is with the updates.

And once I faced the same problem and error was unrecognised... it was because of resources that were in MB's 
Heqvy to load so the app crashed every time I compiled and used it. Just check if it can help

Comment: I am little new here. Do I have to change all the versions of com.android.support* dependency in gradle file or just the appcompat?

Comment: @pagarwal don't worry eveyone is newbie at certain point, yes try to change all the dependency and hope it will work for you and yes try to use the lastest version of android studio :)

Comment: Thank you!  will come back with more queries if there are

Comment: you are most Welcomed :)